# Increasing ALSA's buffer size

Tags: sound, bash, alsa, jack

I'm trying to change ALSA's original buffer size, in order to increase it. Until now, I had no luck.

- I've tried to execute the commands listed in http://pastebin.com/4FibYN0U, however,I don't have that file and directory. Even if I create and edit them, it won't work. I even tried to create the ".h" file in my home directory, and nothing changes.
- Later on, I tried to create an ".asoundrc" file in ~ following the setps in http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc, and it didn't succeed.
- Lastly, I thought I could edit the buffer size via QjackCtl; I tried so, but I don't think changing the Periods/Buffer value will affect ALSA's buffer size.

Is there any way I can increase this buffer?

Comment: If you want this because you have clicks on a slow/old pc, it is better to   disable pulseaudio  :  run this commands:  "echo autospawn=no > ~/.pulse/client.conf "  then  "pulseaudio -k"